# Is there a Wordpress Plugin to Post an image to Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I am looking for a Wordpress plugin to upload an image from my wordpress post to Facebook page. NOTE: I want just the image to be uploaded. Not the Post and the excerpt etc.

There is a software PostPlanner that does it manually.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=DcNdppDW_ew

But I want to do it automatically from the Wordpress Plugin. I am not an expert in PHP. I just need the name of Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the [Facebook Page Publish](http://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/facebook-page-publish) claims it's possible. But I'm unsure if this plugin will work out-of-the-box like that.  If it doesn't, he offers [specific instructions on how to modify his plugin to accomplish this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pictures-from-excerpt-in-fb-page-post?replies=11), and it seems relatively simple.

The plugin doesn't get rave reviews, but that's normal for people who don't really know how to configure things -- and WordPress has a lot of those types of people.  Good luck.